# Enviar multi valores a un OpenQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, linkedserver

Tengo la siguiente consulta en sql server

```sql
Declare @libro varchar(max)
SET @libro = 'AA,NF'
OPENQUERY(ORACLEPD, 'SELECT * FROM LibroMayor where tipoLibro in (''+@libro+'')')
```

Y no me muestra ningún dato, pero si hago lo siguiente sí:

```sql
OPENQUERY(ORACLEPD, 'SELECT * FROM LibroMayor where tipoLibro in (''AA,''NF'')')
```

Comment: Usa un vector/arreglo, para mandar los datos, ya que ahí solo pasas una cadena

Comment: no hay vectores o arreglos en SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Listo hice mi propia solucion (funciona para mi) les comparto si a alguien le ayuda.

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @tb as TABLE(       
       VALORES VARCHAR(MAX) )
    
    SET @var = 'AA,NF' SET @var2 = ''
    
    INSERT INTO @tb 
    SELECT value FROM string_split(@var,',')
    
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM @tb) 
            BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM @tb)>1  
               BEGIN    
               SET @var2 = @var2 + (''''+(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @tb)+'''')+''','''     
               DELETE TOP(1) FROM @tb   
               END      
                  ELSE          
                      BEGIN             
                          SET @var2 = @var2 + (''''+(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @tb)+'''')                       
                          DELETE TOP(1) FROM @tb            END     END

    
    SELECT @var2
```

Resultado de vuelve: **'AA'',''NF'**